# How to start an Android intent with data and package name in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-intent, android-deep-link

I have the following command that works correctly using Android debug bridge:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.paytr.com/payment?paymentSessionToken=$token" com.provisionpay.softpos.paytr
```

How to translate this to Flutter?

## Attempts Made

### 1. Using `url_launcher`

```dart
final uri = Uri.parse('https://www.paytr.com/payment?paymentSessionToken=asdasdasd');
launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

This code opens `www.paytr.com` in the browser.

### 2. Using `external_app_launcher`

```dart
await LaunchApp.openApp(
  androidPackageName: 'com.provisionpay.softpos.paytr',
  openStore: false
);
```

This opens the Google Play Store even if the app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) for extra data and more control, something like this:

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: 'https://www.paytr.com/payment?paymentSessionToken=asdasdasd'
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well but this also launches the browser. Does this work for you?